# Need to slightly tweak this code...need it to find exact match and I'm out of my league

Tags: vba

```
Public Function FindCodes(keywords As Range, text As String)
    'FindCodes = "TEST"

    Dim codeRows As Collection
    Dim codeString As String
    Set codeRows = New Collection

    'Find Codes
    For Each Item In keywords
        Dim keywordArr() As String
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0
        If Item.Row <> 1 Then 'Ignore first row
            keywordArr() = Split(Item, ",")
            'On Error Resume Next
            On Error GoTo ErrHandler
            For Each s In keywordArr()
                If InStr(LCase(text), LCase(s)) <> 0 Then
                    codeRows.Add Item.Row, CStr(Item.Row)
                End If
            Next s
        End If
    Next Item

    'Build Codes String
    If codeRows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim codeArr() As String
        'Set codeArr = New Collection
        'Dim i As Integer
        'i = 0
        ReDim codeArr(codeRows.Count)
        For Each s In codeRows
            'codeArr.Add s, CStr(Worksheets("Codes").Range("A" & s).Value)
            codeArr(i) = Worksheets("Codes").Range("A" & s).Value
            'Set i = Worksheets("Codes").Range("B" + s).Value
            i = i + 1
        Next s
    End If

    'FindCodes = Join(codeArr, ",")

    If UBound(codeArr) > 1 Then
        FindCodes = Join(codeArr, ",")
    ElseIf UBound(codeArr) = 1 Then
        FindCodes = codeArr(0)
    Else
        FindCodes = ""
    End If

ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = 457 Or Err.Number = 0 Or Err.Number = 20 Then
        'foo = someDefaultValue
        Resume Next
    Else
        'Err.Raise Err.Number
        FindCodes = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End If

End Function

Sub temp()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Worksheets("Codes").Range("B:B")
    MsgBox FindCodes(r, ".")
End Sub
```

Comment: Basically, this is a custom macro that a co-worker developed for me to locate phrases in a qualitative research database. I need the code to find exact match...for instance, if the code is "a1.1", I need it to also be able to find "a.1.1.2" without double-counting

Comment: Use "=" for exact match.

Comment: `If LCase(text) = LCase(s) Then`

Comment: If InStr(LCase(text), LCase(s)) <> 0 Then  - it is not working when I replace with above

Comment: It's possible you need to Trim() the values before comparison. If that doesn't work then you'll need to provide some sample data.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to  clearly explain the problem you're having and ask a *specific question* related to the code you've posted. We shouldn't have to guess what you're trying to do or what the problem is, or try to figure out what you're asking. It's up to you to do those things so that we can try to help.

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity of this post guys. I was rushed and I also do not have a good understanding of vba. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems over-complex, but maybe I'm misunderstanding what it's supposed to do.

Try this:

```
Public Function FindCodes(keywords As Range, text As String)

    Dim c As Range, keywordArr, s, rv

    'only look at used cells
    Set keywords = Application.Intersect(keywords, keywords.Worksheet.UsedRange)

    For Each c In keywords.Cells
        If c.Row > 1 And Len(c.Value) > 0 Then 'Ignore first row and empty cells
            keywordArr = Split(c.Value, ",")
            For Each s In keywordArr
                If LCase(Trim(s)) = LCase(Trim(text)) Then
                    'grab value from ColA and go to next cell
                    rv = rv & IIf(Len(rv) = 0, "", ",") & c.EntireRow.Cells(1).Value
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next s
        End If
    Next c
    FindCodes = rv
End Function
```